# Displaying an Entity in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I was tasked of making a shift managing web app.

I have used OpenSkedge (an open-source web app).

One of my tasks is that each user should have a Skill Set.

I have added a functionality where you add these Skill Sets, and I have another view which displays information for the user.

**User Controller:**

```
/**
 * Finds and displays a User entity.
 *
 * @param integer $id ID of user
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function viewAction($id)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if (is_null($id)) {
        $id = $this->getUser()->getId();
    }

    $entity = $em->getRepository('OpenSkedgeBundle:User')->find($id);
    VarDumper::dump($entity);  
    if (!$entity instanceof User) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find User entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    return $this->render('OpenSkedgeBundle:User:view.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'skillset'    => $entity->getSkillset(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**SkillSet Entity:**

```
<?php
// src/OpenSkedge/AppBundle/Entity/SkillSet.php
namespace OpenSkedge\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\KeyValueStore\Mapping\Annotations as KeyValue;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * OpenSkedge\AppBundle\Entity\SkillSet
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="os_skillset")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class SkillSet 
{
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $skillSet;
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $skillNumber;

      /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="user", inversedBy="sset")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    public function getSkillSet()
    {
        return $this->skillSet;
    }
    public function setSkillSet($s){
        $this->skillSet = $s;
        return $this;

    }
    public function getSkillnumber()
    {
        return $this->skillNumber;
    }
    public function setSkillnumber($nm){
         $this->skillNumber = $nm;
         return $this;
    }
    public function getUser(){
        return $this->user;

    }
    public function setUser(\OpenSkedge\AppBundle\Entity\User $u = null){
        $this->user = $u;
        return $this;
    }


}
```

**View Form:**

```
{% extends 'OpenSkedgeBundle:Dashboard:index.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}{{ app_brand_name() }} - {{ entity.name }}{% endblock %}
{% block modulecontent %}
<div class="span12">
    <h3>{{ entity.name }}</h3>
    {% if app.user.id == entity.id %}
    <div class="btn-group header-control">
        <a class="btn" href="{{ path('user_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
    </div>
    {% elseif is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    <form action="{{ path('user_delete', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="post">
    <div class="btn-group header-control">
        <a class="btn" href="{{ path('user_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
        {% if app.user.id != entity.id and delete_form is defined %}
        {{ form_widget(delete_form) }}
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</button>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    </form>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="btn-group header-control">
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ path('user_schedules', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Schedules</a>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ path('user_positions', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Positions</a>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ path('user_supervisors', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Supervisors</a>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ path('user_employees', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Employees</a>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <td>{{ entity.username }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Role</th>
                <td>{{ entity.group.name }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% if entity.workphone %}
            <tr>
                <th>Work Phone</th>
                <td>{{ entity.workphone }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% if entity.homephone %}
            <tr>
                <th>Home Phone</th>
                <td>{{ entity.homephone }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% if entity.location %}
            <tr>
                <th>Location</th>
                <td>{{ entity.location }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <td>{{ entity.email }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% if entity.min %}
            <tr>
                <th>Minimum Hours</th>
                <td>{{ entity.min }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% if entity.max %}
            <tr>
                <th>Maximum Hours</th>
                <td>{{ entity.max }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% if entity.hours %}
            <tr>
                <th>Requested Hours</th>
                <td>{{ entity.hours }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% if entity.notes %}
            <tr>
                <th>Notes</th>
                <td>{{ entity.notes }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
            {% if entity.supnotes %}
            <tr>
                <th>Supervisor Notes</th>
                <td>{{ entity.supnotes }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            <tr>
                <th>Color</th>
                <td><span class="label" style="background-color: {{ entity.color }};">{{ entity.color }}</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Active</th>
                <td>{% if entity.isactive == 1 %}yes{% else %}no{% endif %}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <h3>Skillsets</h3>
    <ul class="skillset">
         {% for set in skillset %}
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The following shows a dump of a User Entity:

[image: User Entity]

As you can see, the user has a set property which includes the Skill Sets which have been added in the new form.

However, the following doesn't display such skillsets in the page:

```
<h3>Skillsets</h3>
<ul class="skillset">
     {% for set in skillset %}
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I do not see a property `skillSet` in your User-class in the screenshot?

Comment: Also yor for-loop is empty. Probably you want to do something like: ` {% for set in skillset %}{{ set.skillset }}{% endfor %}`

Comment: skillset is a string in your Entity. You can't do a for on a string.

Comment: @codeneuss No skillset is a string-property inside the Skillset-class. I fell into the same trap when reading it first.

Comment: and as @dbrumann mentioned you forgot to echo your skillset ;)

Comment: @dbrumann .. ups .. yes than only the echo-part.

Comment: Make sure the word "set" in the for loop is not a key word in twig.. that might cause a problem.

Comment: {% for set in skillset %} {{ set.skillset }}{% endfor %} Doesnt display them either

Comment: If i do {{entity.skillset|length}} is 0, so the for loop won't start

Comment: You can call `{{ dump(skillset) }}` in your template to look if the data is in there. If it is empty, you might have an issue inside `$user->getSkillSet()`